# set custom and current time clock

Tags: android

I have an alarm activity and i want to set the clock to 12:00 if it's the first time the user enter to the activity but when an alarm is set and the user trying to change i want to set to the current time.

Here is where i set the clock:

```
private class TimePickerFragment2 extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c     = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour             = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute           = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(ActivityAlarm.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
        {       

            int callCount = 0;   //To track number of calls to onTimeSet()              
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) 
            {                    
                 int containerElementId = 0;
                 String keySelected     = null;                  
                 if(callCount == 0)    
                 {
                    switch (elementId) {
                        case R.id.start_time:
                            containerElementId = R.id.start_time_container;             
                            keySelected = "start_time";
                            break;
                        case R.id.end_time:
                            containerElementId = R.id.end_time_container;
                            keySelected = "end_time";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                     TextView timeContainer = (TextView)findViewById(containerElementId);
                     String correctedMinute = null;
                     if(selectedMinute == 10){
                         correctedMinute = "00";
                     }
                     if(selectedMinute < 10)
                     {
                         correctedMinute = "0"+selectedMinute;
                     }
                     else{
                         correctedMinute = Integer.toString(selectedMinute);
                     }
                     timeContainer.setText(selectedHour+":"+correctedMinute);
                     if(keySelected == "start_time"){
                         startTime = selectedHour+":"+correctedMinute;
                     }
                     else{
                         endTime = selectedHour+":"+correctedMinute;
                     }

                 }
                 callCount++;    // Incrementing call count.
            }
        }, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ActivityAlarm.this));
        tpd.setTitle("Set Time");           
        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return  tpd;
    }
```